# Can't set current day on DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

This is my code:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(OtherEventActivity.this, R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme,
    new DateSetListener(), mYear, (mMonth), mDay);
try {
      dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
} catch (Exception e) {}

dialog.show();
```

When I start app I can't press on the current day on Android 5 (higher or below works good).

**UPD** - I tried this too:

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in android 5. The date picker does not allow you to pick current date if you set max date as today. The workaround i used was

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
      dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() +  TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(24));
else
     dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Its not a perfect solution but it works.